Adjusting the top and bottom margins independently of the left and right one when using exam.cls
I just started using LaTeX and am kind of stuck on this. I want to change the top and bottom margins of a solution box in the exam class to a different value than the left and right one. Right now, I can change the length of FrameSep to adjust the margins in the solution box. However, this will affect the margins of all sides of the solution box, which I don't want (I want to be able to control what the top and bottom values will such that they will be different from the left and right margins). I've tried looking in the exam.cls file and thought it might be in the TheSolution environment or MakeFramed but am not really sure what to head there. I have also tried using \makeatletter and makeatother to adjust the margins but this will affect the margins of all sides. This is what I have currently:
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\bfseries\lbrack\thequestion.\rbrack}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{1em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}
}
\pointname{}
\pointformat{\bfseries\boldmath(Lecture \thepoints)}
% \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\bfseries\thequestion)}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{\textbf{(\roman{subpart})}}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\exam@FrameSep}{2.5em}% overkill
\makeatother

I have also tried using tcolorbox instead but it doesn't look the same as pdf viewers have issues with it. I learned that this is because of it filling the back of the box with white. I am aware that you can change the opacity of the back of the box to be transparent with standard jigsaw but now the box, when broken across multiple pages, will not be a complete box (the bottom line will be missing. This is my current approach with tcolorbox that uses enhanced but, as mentioned, it's not preferred because it becomes visually distorted in pdf viewers.
\newtcolorbox{answerbox}{
    colback = white,
    colframe = black,
    boxrule = 0.4pt,
    sharp corners,
    left = 0.45in,
    right = 0.45in,
    top = 0.25in,
    bottom = 0.25in,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    skin first = enhanced,
    skin middle = enhanced,
    skin last = enhanced
}

My desired output is a solution box with left and right margins of 0.45 and top and bottom margins of 0.25. I have attached an image of it below.


Note that exam class and geometry don't play well together.  See section 10 (page 102).

Thanks for the help, Simon!

In this example two dimensions are defined. \TBboxsep sets the margins at the top and bottom of the solution box.  \LRboxsep sets   the left and right margins.
So \setlength{\TBboxsep}{0.25in} and \setlength{\LRboxsep}{0.45in} will produce a solution box with left and right margins of 0.45in, and top and bottom margins of 0.25in. (first example)
(the optional \colorsolutionboxes was set).

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{exam}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor} %<<<< just for colors

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\bfseries\lbrack\thequestion.\rbrack}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{
    \addtolength{\labelwidth}{1em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}
}

\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}
\pointformat{\bfseries\boldmath(\thepoints)}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}

\colorsolutionboxes % Optional 
\definecolor{SolutionBoxColor}{RGB}{0,240,40} % Optional, default: lightgray

%***************************************************** added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\TBboxsep}
\newlength{\LRboxsep}

\setlength{\TBboxsep}{0.25in}% Margin top and bottom <<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\LRboxsep}{0.45in}% Margin left and right <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\exam@FrameCommand}
{\fbox}
{\colorfbox{lightgray}}
{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\colorfbox}
{\color{#1}\fbox{\color{saved@color}#2}}
{\color{#1}\fbox{\color{saved@color}\hspace{\dimexpr\LRboxsep-\TBboxsep}#2\hspace{\dimexpr\LRboxsep-\TBboxsep}}}
{}{}

\xpretocmd{\colorfbox}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{\TBboxsep}}{}{}
%***************************************************** 

\begin{document}
    \printanswers
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question[10] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah 
        
        \begin{solution}
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
        \end{solution}
        
        \setlength{\TBboxsep}{0.25in} 
        \setlength{\LRboxsep}{0.0in} 
        
        \begin{solution}
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
        \end{solution}
        
        \setlength{\TBboxsep}{0.0in}
        \setlength{\LRboxsep}{0.45in}
        
        \begin{solution}
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
        \end{solution}
                
        \setlength{\TBboxsep}{0.25in}
        \setlength{\LRboxsep}{0.25in}
                
        \begin{solution}
            blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah
        \end{solution}
    
    \end{questions}

\end{document}

Used  exam.cls    2023/07/09 Version 2.704
